# Microsoft Excel- How to convert an text file without line breaks, no common separator please advise

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editors

I have a notepad with huge content but without any line breaks,  and no common separator like commma, colon or even tab :(.. please advise, I need to split find a particular text which appears multiple times in the text cell. Text to column line breaks is not working-.  The control+j function. Please advise

Comment: Take a look at the unadulterated TXT file with a hex editor. There could be non-printing characters like nulls (0x00) that are delimiting the text. Failing that, VBA could potentially split on anything, not just a single character.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't put a clear example of what you want to do, save your files before starting and back them up, as you might need some trial and error.

Use a text editor that supports, like Notepad++. Lets pretend your line-split string is "One". Change the search mode to "Extended" and search for "One".

If it's finding what you expect, change to the Replace tab and in the replace box use \r\n (yes, those are backslashes) to change the "One"s into new rows or \t to change them to new columns.

Paste contents to excel.