# How to insert new line separator on regular (every 13th) intervals of delimiter in text file which has no new line separator

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editing, newlines, textfiles

I have a TXT file which has some raw data. I need to convert them into Excel, but my attempts are not successful. The file has hundreds of times the delimiter (separator) and that helps me convert to Excel, but all data comes in single row. My data doesn't have any marker/separator for new line. I know that the data has 12 columns. So on 13th delimiter it should have a new line and the data can go to new row.

I have read many websites for the same, but nowhere found the same situation. Here on this website I have [found little similarity but the user has not delimiter](https://superuser.com/questions/1474935/microsoft-excel-how-to-convert-an-text-file-without-line-breaks-no-common-sepa) in the data. So not useful to me. What can I do?

Comment: What version of Excel?  Windows or Mac?  How long is your string?

Comment: I use MS Office 2010. My string is currently in trial is almost 3 to 4pages in MS Word but later it can be more. As of now I got the solution from ZygD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Notepad++ to replace every 13th separator symbol with newline.

Let's say your separator is `@`.

1. Open your .txt file with Notepad++
2. *Search* -> *Replace...*
3. *Find what:* `((?:.*?\@){12}.*?)\@`
   *Replace with:* `$1\n`
   Check *Wrap around*
   *Search Mode* = *Regular expression*
   *Replace All*

<sup>Note: If your separator is not `@`, in the pattern in step 3 replace the `@` with your separator.</sup>

Comment: It's quite difficult to explain regex. At least you need to be familiar with terminology. Even if I tried, I cannot do it better than this example: https://regex101.com/r/Kz0jpu/1 . Here you will see all the explanations of this particular regex match example. Read the *EXPLANATION* section on the right if you're interested. Note that in this example I used 3rd `@` instead of 13th, just for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Similar (ZygD: thanks for the RE !) but in perl rather than NotePad++

<ifile  perl -ne " s/((?:.*?@){12}.*?)@/$1\n/g ; print; "  >rfile

where ifile is your input file

```
  rfile is results

  the "@" is your separator - change to fit your case

  This matches the requested 13 (12+1)
```

Will someone try PowerShell?